# Web Service to Trigger another Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

Is it possible to trigger a web service from within a web service?

```
/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "bookFlight")
public String bookFlight(@WebParam(name = "destination")
String destination, @WebParam(name = "seats")
int seats) {
    try {
        String ret = composite.bookFlight(destination, seats);
            if(composite.checkDistance(destination) > 15)
            {

            }
        return ret;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException_Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(compositeBookings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException_Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(compositeBookings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the empty if function body I need to trigger another web service...

Any takers??

Here is the web service I need to launch from the if statement

```
/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "bookHotel")
public String bookHotel(@WebParam(name = "destination")
String destination, @WebParam(name = "rooms")
int rooms) {        
    try {
        String ret = composite.bookHotel(destination, rooms);            
        return ret;
    } catch (myhotels.InterruptedException_Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(compositeBookings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (myhotels.FileNotFoundException_Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(compositeBookings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is possible, generate client of the service you want to call and invoke that service from there,

But if you have access to the code of that service , use its service layer directly rather than invoking a SOAP from there

Comment: I have access to the code, however it then requires user input just as the parent service does...

Comment: `however it then requires user input just as the parent service does..` didn't get this point, you mean that service is taking parameters ? if this is what you mean than you can directly pass the param like a simple java method

Comment: Yes it takes parameters sorry. User defined though, the same as the first one - @WebParam's

Comment: ok, try invoking them using simple java way , it should get invoked

Comment: I've updated the original post. I'm doing this in netbeans. when I test the first web service, I get the input boxes to satisfy the web parameters. I just need to invoke the second web service, or do something to that effect, that prompts the user for more input for the parameters.

Comment: Have you try invoking it like a simple method invocation ??